# Why the outcome of LinearRegression() prediction is absurd?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, linear-regression

I'm trying to predict the future population of Russia. I have the data of number o Russia citizens between 1960 and 2019.

I'm using scikit-learn's LinearRegression(), below is the code.

The case is, the outcome is absurd! Why is that? I can't find the source of the problem.
I provided model with essential data. Instructed it to learn. Seems like an easy prediction, but it went bad :(. Help!

`X = population['years']`
`y = population['Population']`
`model = LinearRegression()`
`model.fit(np.array(X).reshape(-1,1), y)`
`future = np.round(model.predict(np.array([2025]).reshape(-1,1)))`
`future == array([1.52775894e+08])`

Comment: What about that prediction is bad to you? looks like population is increasing by 10 million in 5 years. seems reasonable.

Comment: The case it is absurd because I've included data before USSR collapse. As should be both RF and USSR treated in the matter treated differently (since shrinked territory, different economy etc.) I tried to include data only since 1990 and predictions seems much more reasonable. Now I'm to include birth rate and population age spread to get better and more accurate predictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That number means 1.52775894 times 10^8 which equals to 152,775,894 which is a little higher than 152 million people. It seems reasonable.

Comment: Can I convert these values to integer anyhow?

Comment: Well, try `int(future[0])` to convert it to integer.

Answer (score 0):

the output is in scientific notation
how to read these numbers are:
1st_number'e' + 2nd_number = 1st_number * 10^2nd_number
******python code*********
X= 1.52775894e+08
print('%.08f' % X)